# Add friend request notification

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, socket.io, notifications

I am working on add friend functionality in my site. My technology stack is reactjs, nodejs, socket.io and mongodb. I am allowing user to click on add friend button and I am storing following information to DB. I.e., requester, recipient and status.

Now I want to send a notification to the recipient about the friend request and for that I am using socket.io in server side and socket.io-client in client side.

To send a notification I am emitting socket in my component after add friend request action call

```
let data = {}
data.loginId = loginId;
data.friendId = friendId;
this.props.submitFriendRequest(data)
socketClient.emit('new friend request', data);
```

Now, in server side I am listening to that event and emitting new event with info

```
socket.on('new friend request', (friend) => {
  io.sockets.emit('new friend', friend);
});
```

In client side I am listening to new friend event and rendering notifications

```
socketClient.on('new friend', (data) => {
//below I am checking current loginId and the recipient id are some and if so I am showing the notification      
if(this.props.loginId==data.friendId){
      this.setState({
        notifications: data
      })
    }
});
```

but with that I am able to display a notification to recipient when user is logged in currently but the problem is that it displays only once and if recipient refreshes the page then the notification is disappearing. Also if recipient logout and login back the notification is not displayed.

I am not getting an idea how to listen to that event and show notification until the recipient accept or reject that friend request. If recipient don't see that notification then whenever he/she login or refresh the pages the notification has to be there.

I am very new to socket.io.